# How UIScrollView setContentSize works

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

`ContentSize` is the `property` of `UIScrollView`. In my `UITableView` subclass I implemented this

```
- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)contentSize {
        NSLog(@"contentSize = %f, %f", contentSize.width, contentSize.height);
        NSLog(@"self.contentSize = %f, %f", self.contentSize.width, self.contentSize.height);
}
```

From where this `contentSize` is coming from? and why `contentSize` and `self.contentSize` have different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from the table view delegate when it supplies the number of sections and rows and the height of the rows.

The values are different because one is the existing size and one's the newly calculated size, which will happen any time you ask the table to reload data / add / remove rows or sections.

Comment: Thanks for replying, please can you tell in bit detail why call super.contentSize, Its not even mention in apple doc.

Comment: If you override a method then you're replacing the implementation and you either need to take on the responsibility for that method or call super to do the normal work and then add your work afterwards. Currently all you do it log so your table view should be basically unusable...

Answer (score 0):

`contentSize` is a parameter to the method `setContentSize:`. This method is over-riding `setContentSize:`, so it is accepting a new value for the content size. If you want to log it and have it work properly, you also need to add the line `super.contentSize = contentSize;`.